# Dropdown Not Changing After Data Is Updated,because two API's are calling at the same time

Tags: api, typescript, service, angular5

```
this.rateService.deleterateSheet(formattedData).toPromise().then(
      rateData => {
        alert('deleting')
        this.rateService.gettingRates(this.accountId).toPromise().then(
          ratesData1 => {
            this.rates = (ratesData1['data']);
            this.snackBar.open('RateSheet Deleted', 'OK', { duration: 3000});
          }
        );

      }
    );
```

> Now it's working
>
> I can't use alert.
>
> Is there any method other than delay to slow my second API call in angular 5
>
> alert I used to slow my API call
>
> I tried two of them(delay,normal method) separate. Didn't work
>
> Is there any method

Comment: -> I use this.ngOnInit() didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You change your code like this ,

```
this.rateService.deleterateSheet(formattedData).toPromise().then(
      rateData => {
            this.rateService.gettingRates(this.accountId).toPromise().then(
              rates => {
               const index = this.rates.indexOf(this.ratesheet_name);
               this.rates.splice(index, 1);
              }
            );

      });
```